# Do while loop check for last iteration

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

This may sound like an elementary question, but I want to check whether my thought process is correct.

I have a do while loop and I want to check when the loop has entered the last iteration so as to either set a value or not. I have come with this sort solution but doesn't feel and I was wondering whether there is a another way.

```
 do 
  { 
      int iterationCheck ++;

      if( iterationCheck! = counter)
       // Do something 
       counter++;
   } while (true)
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Comment: This won't even compile, far less run correctly. Also, why not just use a `for` loop here?

Comment: Well this is simply out lining a thought process to show what the problem is rather than giving you something to compile

Comment: It would be easier to understand the question if you showed the actual code that you were trying. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Seems like the best way would be to do an additional check on the `while` condition inside the loop. Your current example is not good because you do not have a "final iteration" (you've presented us with an infinite loop). Consider an example like: `do { cart.AddItem(); } while (!cart.IsFull)`. Then what you would do is: `do { cart.AddItem(); if (cart.IsFull) { // this is the last iteration } } while (!cart.IsFull)`

Comment: Agree with @RufusL. Also, sometimes you put the exit criterion in the middle of the loop block. Something like `while (true) { Abc(); Def(); if (isLastNow) { Xyz(); break(); /* exits! */ } Ghi(); Jkl(); } /* loop end */`. That is fine. Of course, most often you want the exit condition to be either first or last, which is why the `while` and `do` statements are designed the way they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you could do this to count the iteration
But put the 'int iterationCheck=0' variable declaration before the do/while scope.

You could go for a 'for' loop too ( which would be better )

However it all depends on the condition of your loop.
Because we can't infer the 'out' condition of your loop so we can't provide a accurate answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I am on train and the code is at work. The while condition calls a method that checks a number of things and doesn't really imply on the iteration

Comment: Rufus comment could be your solution then.