# How many times with the following loop iterate?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i90QC.png)

my classmate thinks it's 10 I know it's 11. I can't explain it properly so anyone wanna give it a shot?

The variable starts at 10. Each time it passes it decrements by one and the loop exits when x isn't greater than 0. so when x becomes 0 the loop exits. so it happens from 10 to 0. That's 11 times.

Comment: Have you [tried it](https://ideone.com/3jUz5U)?

Comment: Depends on where you check the condition and when you subtract 1. If you check the condition before it will go 10 times

Comment: why dont you try yourself and print the value and see how many times the loop is running?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently this question is likely to be closed because it's easily answerable with the use of an IDE. Homework questions are generally unanswered to promote self-learning amongst users.

Comment: it's not a homework question. it's from a sample mid term. the value is printed in that order it shows ten but logically it should be 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do while loop check for last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349933/do-while-loop-check-for-last-iteration)

Comment: @BCIT_Student_2019 Which is, in essence, a homework question. Regardless of the purpose within a school environment, trivia questions about written code will remain unanswered because they aren't helpful for future users of the site.

Comment: i know the right answer, it is 11. dunno how to explain it to my buddy. thats all

Comment: the condition is tested after the loop block executes so it is 11. looking at the output doesnt do much considering where the print statement is

Comment: run it how the question has it. then run it with the sysout outside of the loop and ull see a 0 output

Comment: Might be helpful to no confuse "iteration of the loop body" and "increment/decrement operations". You've explicitly asked about how many times the loop will iterate and when argue that `x--` will executed 11 times. Those are two different things, even when they happen in the same loop context. So your classmate were right, you just didn't understand your own question.

Comment: it iterates 11 times but it prints 10 times. try putting the print statement outside as well.

Comment: Ok, then lookup what "iterates" means.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more than you want to know but here you go.

Your example is no different than `for (x = 10; x < 0; x--);`

Most loops have a start, end, and an increment. (I won't say `all loops` because someone will come up with an obscure example to prove me wrong).

With for loops there are two cases to consider.

1. for (x = start; x <= end; x+=inc);  // I refer to this as closed
2. for (x = start; x < end; x+inc);  // I refer to this as open

For the closed loop, the number of times is computed as:

```
(end-start)/inc + 1
```

The open loop is more complicated in that 1 must be subtracted from
`end` to force it to be a `closed` loop.  That can be computed as

```
(end-1-start)/inc + 1
```

This also works if you change the positions of `start` and `end` and do a `decrement` of the increment.

In your case it would be (10 - 1 - 0)/1 + 1 = 10.

And here is some test code to play with to check out each loop type.

```java
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Random r = new Random();
          for (int t = 0; t < 10_000; t++) {
             int realCountClosed = 0;
             int realCountOpen = 0;
             int start = r.nextInt(10);
             int end = r.nextInt(30) + 11;
             int inc = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
             for (int i = start; i <= end; i += inc) {
                realCountClosed++;
             }
             for (int i = start; i < end; i += inc) {
                realCountOpen++;
             }
             int computedCountClosed = (end - start) / inc + 1;

             int computedCountOpen = ((end - 1) - start) / inc + 1;

             if (realCountClosed != computedCountClosed) {
                System.out.println(
                      "Closed: " + realCountClosed + " " + computedCountClosed);
             }

             if (realCountOpen != computedCountOpen) {
                System.out.println(
                      "Open: " + realCountOpen + " " + computedCountOpen);
             }
          }
       }
```

One final note.  In for loops `pre` or `post` increment  (i.e. -- or ++) of values doesn't affect the loop.  This is not the case of `while` loops if the increment is done in the `while` portion of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following loop iterates exactly 10 times, printing the value of `x` from `10` to `1`. The loop stops looping when `x = 0` because 0 is not bigger than 0. This decrementing process happens in `x--` after the program have looped 10 times. Because the loop iterates exactly 10 times, the value of x is printed first then it is decremented by 1, 10 times. So in the end, the final value of x is 0 but the last value of x **that is being printed** is `1`.

Comment: Put the while (x < 0) after int x = 10;

Would that print out the same amount?

Comment: also it's not asking how many times it prints. its asking how many times it iterates

Comment: @BCIT_Student_2019 both are same things here, if you repeat a work 5 times then you do  the work 5 times.

Comment: You can tell how many times it iterates based on how many times it prints. If you're still unsure, here's another way to look at it: the program is decrementing 10 times, resulting for the value of x each loop, respectively: 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0. Counting from nine to zero, it is clear the loop happens 10 times.

Comment: so it doesn't matter if there is a "do" and if the while is placed after or before?

Comment: I think the previous comment may be misleading. *In this specific case* there is no difference between ```do … while``` and ```while … do``` because we know the continuation condition always starts off true.  But *in general*, ```do … while``` always executes at least once, and ```while … do``` may execute zero times.